# How to display calendar for a question in Google Form that asks for date input?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

Is it possible for a form that was created in Google Docs to display calendar of a current month so a user can answer a question that asks about a date?

Answer (score 1):

Including a question of type Date in New Sheets and checking include year results in something like this:

[image: WA18439 example]

Comment: Can you embed just the calendar though?